# Drawing a rectangle in a scrollview?

Tags: android

Can you draw a rectangle in a scrollview? If so how? I did some searching and I was not able to find an answer. Specifically, I want the rectangle IN the scrollview so that when I scroll the rectangle moves with the view, as opposed to a rectangle being on top of the scrollview, where the scrollview would scroll under the rectangle and the rectangle would remain on top where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends `ScrollView` and override `onDraw()`. There you can draw whatever you want. To make the drawing scroll with the content, you should offset the locations with the values you get by `getScrollX()` or `getScrollY()`.